# SQL Server addressing a table different than requested then firing "object name xxx invalid"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

From the Object Explorer of SQL Server Management Studio I renamed a table from `nameA` to `nameB`. When I query `SELECT * from nameB` I receive the error

> object name 'nameA' not valid

This happens both from Management Studio and an external application. `SELECT * from nameA` gives the same error.

Restarting the service didn't help. Table name in `sysobjects` is correct. Is there maybe another place where SQL Server looks up table names? Thanks, it's getting me quite crazy :S

I'm using SQL Server 11.0.2100.60

Comment: `Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache`?  Could be pre-execution error checking.  I've seen it happen when creating new tables.  I don't believe I've ever renamed a table, so I don't know about that.

Comment: Are you sure you are querying in the proper database/schema?

Comment: Also you don't have any Service Packs installed for SQL Server. SP3 is out already, see [here](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.be/).

Comment: I've installed SP3 but the problem persists. It seems SQL Server is still looking for the original table name. Any suggestion whether to look in system tables?

Comment: UPDATE: if I go to `Tasks -> Generate scripts -> Select specific database objects` the table name is the original one. It seems that different functionalities of Management Studio take names from different catalogs.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with a workaround:

I generated scripts for table schema and data, dropped the table and run scripts to recreate table schema and data. NOTE: I needed to manually modify the generated scripts because of mistakes in smalldatetime fields which made the generated INSERTs fail.

So it seems that dropping tables resets the "denormalized" SQL Server internal catalog which was left inconsistent somewhen. Thanks MS! ;)